# Unity Dash to search only in Documents

Tags: 12.04, unity-dash, libreoffice, lenses

I have a document (LibreOffice Calc Spreadsheet) which is in my ~/Documents folder. However, I have the same file (older version of it) on a mounted drive.

In the past few weeks I have opened the file from both my ~/Documents folder and from the mounted drive. However, the latest version is the one from ~/Documents.

When I open the Dash and look in the documents lens, of course I will find my file twice there. One from the mounted disk and one from ~/Documents. But I don't know which one is which.

So, my question is: How can I limit the document lens to look for documents only from my /home. Or to exclude mounted disks from the search.

Thanks.

I use Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type *Privacy* in launcher and head to *Files* --> *Don't record activity in the following folders*.

Add any folders you want to exclude from search and you're set to go.

Comment: It's a good tip, thx. I think I knew that one once, but I forgot about it. But, it seems it doesn't work. Do I have to log-out/log-in?

Comment: It doesn't exclude any files retrospectively. You will have to delete your recent history to delete any entries left from the folders you excluded.

Comment: must be too late that I am not able to figure out such trivial tasks on my own. Thx mate.

Comment: You're welcome. We all have those moments ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can select which folders and file types you want indexed under **System Settings>Privacy>Files**.